# Noda B'Yehuda and the Tzavah of Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid

Tags: minhag

The Noda B'Yehuda ([Tinyanah Evan HaEzer Siman 79](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1447&pgnum=325)) famously writes in regards to making a match between a bachelor that has the same name as the father of the potential bride that one need not be concerned about this. Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid in his famous will (tzavah) writes that one shouldn't make such a shidduch.

The Noda B'Yehuda writes very strongly against anyone going against what it says in the Talmud, mentioning specifically other relationships (marriage set-ups) that Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid wrote against and that the Talmud permitted or said even was a mitzvah! He writes so strongly that such a person's words shouldn't be accepted. Because of this however he writes afterwards a reason why perhaps Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid was machmir in these things.

My question is, would the Noda B'Yehuda speak or feel so strongly against other things it says in the Tzavah? For example (and specifically) not taking a haircut on Rosh Chodesh. Would we have any reason to believe that he also perhaps didn't hold of this prohibition? (Arguably, it's more difficult to believe as much, since this prohibition was already brought in poskim by the time the Noda B'Yehuda lived.) Do we have a proof to this from anywhere or a reason to think that he would also disagree with this point and others?

(Please help add tags to this then remove this line from the question.)

Comment: for names, he had evidence that Chazal did the exact opposite. so maybe not.

Comment: "he does come to "save" so to speak what it says in the Tzvah and why Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid wrote it" is completely opaque to me.

Comment: @msh210 as I've said perhaps too many times it can sometimes be tricky for me to express myself in English. Save the comments and simply fix it.

Comment: I *did* edit other parts of your post. I couldn't fix that part, as it's completely opaque to me. That is, I don't know what you're trying to say there. The general gist of the question is clear, though, and I upvoted it FWIW.

Comment: IIRC Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid "forbids" it only if the names are duplicate for 2 generations.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Now a days I've found many minhagim in this (those that are makpid, how, why, which way, etc) and "eitzos" when the names are the same and the both sides still want. My wife is a Shadchan and it's amazing what people will want/look for/ask for. My Shver made a Shidduch and took a son-in-law with a "similar" name. Same first name, different second names and the son-in-law is called on the first and second, our shver is called only on the first.

Comment: @Yehoshua: I've come across that too, but don't blame it on Rebbe Yehuda HaChossid. :-)